# WebAPI Put returns HTTPResponseMessage null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a requirement to implement simple edit functionality.I am using webapi service to update my test object.
I am calling the below method from the controller post request.

This is the controller which calls a metod in test calls wich inturn calls the put service

```
public ActionResult TestEdit(Test test)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // objTest is returned null
    HttpResponseMessage objtest = TestDatabaseService.TestEdit(test.testID, test);
  }
}

// Method which calls put service testDataService
public HttpResponseMessage TestEdit(int id, Test test)**
{
   string uri = baseUri + "Test/" + id;
   using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
   {
      Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Test>(uri, application);
            return response.Result;
   }
}

// The webapi service put method 
public HttpResponseMessage PutTest(int id, Test test)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && id == test).testID)
  {
    db.Entry(test)).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
    }

    // The status code is set to indicate the save is success
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
  }
  else
  {
    // If save failed
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
  }
}
```

.
 public Application TestCreate(Test test) 
{ string uri = baseUri + "Test"; 
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
 { Task response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, test); 
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsy‌​nc().Result).Result; 
} 
}

Comment: can someone show some light to this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API method not returning the response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338684/web-api-method-not-returning-the-response)

Comment: Are you able to understand what the probelm i am facing. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result
```

The response already *is* an `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response
```

There's nothing to deserialize.  All you have to do is *await* it to get its result.  First, make your method `async`:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TestEdit(int id, Test test)
```

Then await the result in the method:

```
return await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Test>(uri, test);
```

This will effectively return the `HttpResponseMessage` object.  So make this `async` as well:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestEdit(Test test)
```

And await your other method:

```
HttpResponseMessage objtest = await TestDatabaseService.TestEdit(test.testID, test);
```

It's not really clear why you need to abstract this behind multiple methods, but if the semantics make sense for your needs then that's fine.  There's no immediate harm to it.

But basically you're trying to tell a JSON de-serializer to de-serialize something that, well, isn't a JSON representation that object.  So the result will be `null`, because the de-serialization will quietly fail.  But the point is that you don't need to de-serialize anything here.  `PutAsJsonAsync<T>` already returns an object of type `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: Thanks David, thanks for showing me the right path. I am using vs 2010 . .net framework 4.0 . I am not able to add async and await . it is not identifying. I think it is part of 4.5 ?

Comment: @jubi: In That case it seems that you'll have to use the older methods of handling asynchronous operations (with which I'm not entirely familiar), or perhaps use synchronous versions of these operations.  You may be able to get away with directly invoking `.Result` on the tasks, or perhaps invoking `.Wait()`.  However you handle the asynchronous operations, the main point remains the same.  No de-serialization is necessary when just returning an object from a method.

Comment: You saved me. I have modified  like this Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Test>(uri, application);
                return response.Result; and it worked. Thanks a million

Comment: Got a doubt in case of create my code is  public Application TestCreate(Test test)
        {
            string uri = baseUri + "Test";
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<Test>(uri, test);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Test>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result;
            }
        }

Comment: public List<Test> TestIndex()
        {
            string uri = baseUri + "Test/";

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                Task<String> response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<Test>>(response.Result).Result;
            }
        } this gives me the list view of all tests added .a kind of summary.In create and list i am having the deserialization. Do i need to serialize this . is it correct?

Comment: Is it because the index returns aray of object.? I have updated the question with the corrected approach as David suggested.

Comment: @jubi: It's not clear what you're asking in these comments, or how it relates to the original question.

Comment: similar to edit i have functionality to  Add new record and display the all the existing items . This is the code used for both the functionality. My edit issue is resolved. I am not facing any problem with Add and listing any records. I just wonder there the deserialization never failed.i will update the question with Add and display as well for better reading

Comment: Marking this as answer because it works perfectly fine with the Davids code

Comment: @jubi: What about it?  That question already has a good answer.

Comment: @jubi: Look, this is not how Stack Overflow works.  Please keep requests regarding that question on that question itself.  As for the routing, you can define routes in the Global.asax (or any of the setup methods it invokes).  Take a look at route configurations for WebAPI.  You can also just rename your methods, change their parameters, add other controllers, etc.