# Web API method not returning the response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, json-deserialization

I have a requirement to use Web API. I have implemented  Add functionality successfully , and now in the Edit . I am calling the PUT method from my mvc controller thorough and intermediate class and which **returns 
`return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);`**  This is the return from my PUT method

```
public HttpResponseMessage SampleEdit(int sampleId, Sample sample)
        {
            string uri = baseUri + "Sample/" + sampleId;
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Sample>(uri, sample);


                return **JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result;**
            }
        }
```

Here if i debug the put method is called and it is setting the status .

```
HttpResponseMessage message =
DatabaseService.SampleEdit(sample.SampleID,sample);
```

This message  is coming as null if the return statement in PUT is `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);` 
If i use

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,sample);
```

instead it is returning the status. What would be the issue

Comment: Please point me into right direction.

Comment: I've read that 3 times now and I'm none the wiser as to what your actual question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317358/webapi-put-returns-httpresponsemessage-null  . I better explained here with the code.  can you please have a look . Let me know is it clear .

Comment: So what your saying is this question is a duplicate of one you've already asked? you know you shouldn't do that right?

Comment: Please have a read though the [help]

Comment: I didnot know that. I have just started using stackoverfloe 2 weeks back, and did not know much about it. Sorry for making a duplicate question . I will edit this queston with code and will delete any one of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103287/discussion-between-jubi-and-liam).