# How to deserialize

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

How to deserialize Task response using Json .

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, ModelClass modelbject)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && id == modelbject.modelbjectID)
    {
        db.Entry(modelbject).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

I want to derialize this and check the IsSuccessStatusCode in my class where i am calling this put method. How can i achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to derialize this and check the IsSuccessStatusCode in my class where i am calling this put method.

You don't have to "deserialize" anything.  The method returns an `HttpResponseMessage`, which [has the property you're looking for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage).

```
var result = yourController.Put(someId, someObject);
var success = result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

Perhaps the fact that this is a web application is adding some confusion to how you're picturing it.  But if you have a class which directly calls this method, then what you get back is simply an `HttpResponseMessage` object.  Which can be inspected just like any other object.  No *actual* web layer is involved in that interaction.

Comment: I am calling this from an mvc application . i have two project in my solution one is mvc proj and another is mvc webapi

Comment: I wonder if you can look at this , here i have the code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317358/webapi-put-returns-httpresponsemessage-null . I am not sure what mistake i made. I am digging into this issue .

Comment: I am calling this PUT method from my another project that is an mvc project .

Comment: @jubi: It's not clear what you're describing.  In the question you say that you're calling this method directly from another class.  Is that not actually the case?  How do you actually invoke this?  Is your MVC project directly referencing your WebAPI project as a code reference, or are you making an actual HTTP request to a completely separate running instance?  If the problem you're facing is in how you *invoke* this method, then you're going to have to show *that* code in the question.